# c# run query to update sql server database not all records being updated

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server

I'm having issue with running a query in c# that updates a table in sql server.

In total I'm updating about 2500 records in my table. However there are about 350 rows where the acq_rank field is not being updated. So I have checked the query by looking at the cmdText variable and the parameter values. If I copy these values and run the query in sql server manually (bottom of this post) the query updates the table. I'm not sure what is happening.

**UPDATE**

Comparing the records that did update and those that didn't it appears any companies with a comma in their name are the ones not being updated. How do I get round this?

When debugging the code I can see the company names are normally "some name" however when they contain a comma however it looks like "\"some name with comma\""

**C#**

```
 for (int i = 0; i < rankList.Count; i++)
            {
                string cmdText;

                if(rankList[i].company_id == "NULL")                    
                    cmdText = "update MA_DEALS_COUNTRY set acq_rank = @rank where deal_id = @deal and company_id is null and co_name = @coname";                    
                else                    
                    cmdText = "update MA_DEALS_COUNTRY set acq_rank = @rank where deal_id = @deal and company_id = @co_id and co_name = @coname";                    

                _command = new SqlCommand(cmdText, _connection);

                if (rankList[i].company_id == "NULL")
                {
                    _command.Parameters.Add("@deal", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = rankList[i].DealId;
                    _command.Parameters.Add("@coname", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = rankList[i].CoName;
                    _command.Parameters.Add("@rank", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value = rankList[i].Rank;
                }
                else
                {
                    _command.Parameters.Add("@deal", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = rankList[i].DealId;
                    _command.Parameters.Add("@co_id", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = rankList[i].company_id;
                    _command.Parameters.Add("@coname", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = rankList[i].CoName;
                    _command.Parameters.Add("@rank", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value = rankList[i].Rank;
                }

                _command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                Console.WriteLine("row " + i.ToString());
            }
```

**SQL Server Manual Update**

I have included both update statement - one for when the company_id is null and one when it is not

```
declare @rank int
declare @deal varchar(20)
declare @co_id varchar(5)
declare @coname varchar(max)

set @rank = 0
set @deal = '136344MM'
set @co_id = 'AB240'
set @coname = 'Company Capital Partners, Inc.'

update MA_DEALS_COUNTRY set acq_rank = @rank where deal_id = @deal and company_id is null and acquirer_name = @coname

update MA_DEALS_COUNTRY set acq_rank = @rank where deal_id = @deal and company_id = @co_id and acquirer_name = @coname
```

Comment: I think you want to escape special characters in your values from C#, when you have "Morgan's PC" in C#, sql will interprete this differently. To correct it you'll have to pass it as "Morgan''s  PC".

Comment: do you know to deal with commas when going from c# to sql?

Comment: I don't commas are your problem, maybe something else in your update statement is not working correctly. Also, it also a good practice to use stored procedures to avoid things like sql Injection and also provide an easy maintainance when you want to make changes in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is likely when the update statement is comparing **co_name = @coname**. You have to follow the code where this is being compared for a company with a comma.

You also mentioned that instead of "some name," it looks like "\"some name,\""

Try:

A.

```
_command.Parameters.Add("@coname", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Convert.ToString(rankList[i].CoName);
```

B.

```
_command.Parameters.Add("@coname", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = rankList[i].CoName.ToString();
```

C.

Search for the '\' and '"' characters in the string and remove them. This is not the best of ways to go about it as the '\' or '"' should not be there in the first place when the assignment is made.

```
string valueString = rankList[i].CoName.ToString();
            while (valueString.IndexOf('"') > -1)
        {
            if (valueString.Length - 1 == valueString.IndexOf('"'))
                valueString = valueString.Remove(valueString.IndexOf('"'));
            else
            valueString = valueString.Remove(valueString.IndexOf('"'), valueString.IndexOf('"')+1);
        }
        while (valueString.IndexOf('\\') > -1)
        {
            if (valueString.Length - 1 == valueString.IndexOf('\\'))
                valueString = valueString.Remove(valueString.IndexOf('\\'));
            else
            valueString = valueString.Remove(valueString.IndexOf('\\'), valueString.IndexOf('\\')+1);
        }
_command.Parameters.Add("@coname", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = valueString;
```

Comment: none of the above methods make any difference sadly

Comment: I have edited the code to remove unwanted characters in the string, it should work now...

Answer (score 1):

Well, for starters, the following version of the query will work regardless of the nullability of the `@co_id` parameter:

```
update MA_DEALS_COUNTRY set acq_rank = @rank
where deal_id = @deal
and nullif(@co_id, company_id) is null
and co_name = @coname
```

Considering how you test the `rankList[i].company_id` for nullability, this should help.